# How to Implement Email Forword functionality in Laravel 9

Tags: email, laravel-9, laravel-mail, email-forwarding

I have store the Gmail inbox in my database and listed on admin panel, now I want to Forword the received mail to another, how to do that in Laravel.

I have use laminas/laminas-mail package to store, send and reply.

Please Provide suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you recognize, a email has been reseived (eg some sort of events), you could create an (queue) listener and dispatch the mail over:

1. Register an event and listener in the EventServiceProvider by opening the `app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php` file and adding the following code in the listen array:

```php
protected $listen = [
    ReceivedEmailEvent::class => [
        ForwardEmailListener::class,
    ],
];
```

> After registering listeners in your `EventServiceProvider`, use the `event:generate` Artisan command to quickly generate listener classes.

2. Open the `app/Events/ReceivedEmailEvent.php` file and update its contents with the following code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ReceivedEmailEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $fromEmail;
    public $subject;
    public $body;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param string $fromEmail
     * @param string $subject
     * @param string $body
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($fromEmail, $subject, $body)
    {
        $this->fromEmail = $fromEmail;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->body = $body;
    }
}
```

3. Open the app/Listeners/ForwardEmailListener.php file and update its contents with the following code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\ForwardEmailEvent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class ForwardEmailListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ForwardEmailEvent  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ReceivedEmailEvent $event)
    {
        $data = [
            'from' => $event->fromEmail,
            'subject' => $event->subject,
            'body' => $event->body,
        ];

        Http::post('/forward-email', $data);
    }
}
```

4. Create a controller that does the actual forwarding

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class EmailForwardingController extends Controller
{
    public function forward(Request $request)
    {
        // You may want to add some validation, too

        $toEmail = 'your-email@example.com'; // Replace with the email address you want to forward the emails to

        $fromEmail = $request->input('from');
        $subject = $request->input('subject');
        $body = $request->input('body');

        // Forward the email
        Mail::raw($body, function ($message) use ($fromEmail, $toEmail, $subject) {
            $message->from($fromEmail);
            $message->to($toEmail);
            $message->subject($subject);
        });

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Email forwarded successfully']);
    }
}
```

5. To use this controller, you need to define a route that points to the `forward` method of the EmailForwardingController. For example, in your `routes/web.php` file, you can add the following route:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\EmailForwardingController;

Route::post('/forward-email', [EmailForwardingController::class, 'forward']);
```

6. Now, you can fire the ReceivedEmailEvent event whenever you receive an email. For example, you can add the following code in your controller method that receives the email:

```php
use App\Events\ReceivedEmailEvent;

// ...

public function receiveEmail(Request $request)
{
    // Process the received email

    // Fire the ReceivedEmailEvent
    $fromEmail = $request->input('from');
    $subject = $request->input('subject');
    $body = $request->input('body');

    event(new ReceivedEmailEvent($fromEmail, $subject, $body));

    // Return response
}
```

> This is untested and should give you a rough idea of how you might implement such a solution

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be the job scheduler using an artisan command:

1. Create a new Laravel command to handle the forwarding of emails. Run the following command to generate the command file:

```bash
php artisan make:command ForwardEmails
```

2. Open the generated `ForwardEmails` command file located in `app/Console/Commands/` and modify the `handle` method to include the logic for forwarding emails:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Laminas\Mail\Storage\Imap;
use Laminas\Mail\Transport\Smtp;
use Laminas\Mail\Message;

class ForwardEmails extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'emails:forward';

    protected $description = 'Forward received emails to another address';

    public function handle()
    {
        $imap = new Imap([
            'host'     => 'imap.gmail.com',
            'user'     => 'your-email@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'your-password',
            'ssl'      => 'ssl',
        ]);

        foreach ($imap as $message) {
            $forwardedMessage = new Message();
            $forwardedMessage->setEncoding('UTF-8');

            $forwardedMessage->addFrom('your-email@gmail.com', 'Your Name');
            $forwardedMessage->addTo('forward-to@gmail.com', 'Recipient Name');

            $headers = $message->getHeaders();

            foreach ($headers as $header) {
                $forwardedMessage->getHeaders()->addHeader($header);
            }

            $forwardedMessage->setSubject('Fwd: ' . $message->getSubject());

            $body = $message->getBody();
            $forwardedMessage->setBody($body);

            $transport = new Smtp([
                'host'              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'port'              => 587,
                'connection_class'  => 'login',
                'connection_config' => [
                    'username' => 'your-email@gmail.com',
                    'password' => 'your-password',
                    'ssl'      => 'tls',
                ],
            ]);

            $transport->send($forwardedMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, we're using the `Imap` class from the `laminas-mail` package to connect to your Gmail account and retrieve the emails. We then loop through the messages and create a new `Message` instance for each forwarded email. We copy the necessary headers and content from the original email and send it using the `Smtp` transport provided by the package.

> Note: Replace 'your-email@gmail.com' with your actual Gmail address, 'your-password' with your Gmail account password, and 'forward-to@gmail.com' with the email address you want to forward the messages to.

> You may want to create a configuration file for the credentials and use environment variables, which are ignored from any version control.

3. Next, register the command in the app/Console/Kernel.php file by adding it to the $commands array:

```php
protected $commands = [
    // Other commands...
    \App\Console\Commands\ForwardEmails::class,
];
```

4. You can now schedule the command to run automatically at specific intervals. Open the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file and locate the `schedule` method. Add the following code to schedule the `ForwardEmails` command to run every minute:

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // Other scheduled tasks...
    $schedule->command('emails:forward')->everyMinute();
}
```

You can modify the schedule according to your requirements. For more details on scheduling commands in Laravel, refer to the official [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands).

5. Finally, to run the scheduled commands, you need to set up the Laravel scheduler. Open the server's crontab by running crontab -e in your terminal and add the following line at the end of the file

```bash
* * * * * cd /path/to/your/laravel/project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

> If you do not know how to add cron entries to your server, consider using a service such as [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com) which can manage the cron entries for you